# How (break; while) and (continue; loop)

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, break

HHi, I have a small problem, difficult to explain, but I have a while inside a loop.

the context of my plugin calls for a reset of the loop. (continue)
however, I will also need to do (break) in the while.

How i can Break the while and call Continue; for the loop.

here the full context, I know it's hard to read code from a custom context
but here my function scope and what am try target.

look at this line **console.log('=> how break and continue')**
thank for help

```
    // STEP3: BUILD TEXT CHILD
var re = /\w+.|\W/g; // \w+.\s*|\W+ // if wordWrap only
var l = -1; // START AT LINE -1 (line++ at start loop)
var lineX = 0;
var lineY = 0;
var lineHeight = 0; // at end maxheight auto increase
var newLine=true; // jmp line and creat
var dataLine = [];
var maxLineX = this._style.global.wordWrap && this._style.global.wordWrapWidth || false;
var pixiBox = false;;
for(var d=0, newLine=true; d<dataTxt.length; d++){ // loop all dataTxt

    var data = dataTxt[d];
    var dataL = dataLine[l];
    if(newLine){ // INITIALISE NEW LINE AND RESET DATA
        lineY+=lineHeight; 
        lineX = 0; 
        lineHeight = 0; 
        newLine = false; 
        l++;
        dataLine[l] = {width:0, height:0, txtID:[], line:l }; // initialise a new this._dataLines [line]
        var dataL = dataLine[l];
    };

    // create type of elements
    if(!pixiBox){ // if empty pixi box, create new data pixi
        if(data.type==='txt'){ 
            pixiBox = new PIXI.Text(data.value, data.style);
        }else if(data.type==='icon'){ // if icons was not registered, registe to pixiBox;
            pixiBox = new PIXI.Sprite(pixiMS._iconsID[data.value]);
        }else if(data.type==='jmp'){
            pixiBox =  new PIXI.Graphics();
            pixiBox.drawRect(0, 0, 0, dataL.height+data.value);
            newLine = true;
        };
    };



    // check if its ou limit ?
    if(maxLineX && (lineX + pixiBox.width) > maxLineX){
        if(d>5000){confirm('ERROR EXCEED LIMIT WORDWRAP < WORD LENGTH, OR USE BREAK WORDS'); break; }; // protection freeze engine (win) if wrong wordWrap size
        if(data.type==='icon'){newLine = true; d--; continue; }; // reset to a newLine, but keep icons registered 

        // its a text need Split to a new line;
        var letterWidth = pixiBox.width / data.value.length; // calculate width of all letter
        var tmpW = 0; // Temps Width
        while ( (match = re.exec(data.value) ) !== null) {
            var mL = match[0].length; // match txt length 
            if(lineX+tmpW+(mL*letterWidth) > maxLineX){ // if this match exeed , txt befor index become this valur and add extra data after
                if(match.index===0){ // if match index 0 , (this data continue) reset new line 
                    console.log('=> how break and continue');newLine = true; d--; break; continue;
                }else{ // current txt become txt befor , and push new data after
                    data.value = match.input.slice(0, match.index); // text befor the match (if 0 its ok, just empty txt)
                    var after1 = this._newData('jmp', 0, "wordWrapBreak", false);
                    var after2 = this._newData('txt', match.input.slice(match.index), data.tag, data.style);
                    this._dataTxt.splice(d+1, 0, after1,after2); // reconfigu the loop length
                    pixiBox.text =  data.value; // redefine pixi
                    break;
                }

            };
            tmpW+=lineX;
        };
    };


    data.xPos = lineX; 
    data.yPos = lineY; 
    data.line = l;

    // INCREASE TXT POSITION
    lineX += pixiBox.width; // x pos for next pixi element
    dataL.width = lineX; // line width ++ valueOf()
    lineHeight = pixiBox.height>lineHeight&&pixiBox.height||lineHeight;

    dataL.height = lineHeight;
    dataL.txtID.push(d);
    this._childTexts.push(pixiBox); // store child array
    this.addChild(pixiBox);
    pixiBox = false;
};
return this;
```

edit Solved:

```
        if(maxLineX && (lineX + pixiBox.width) > maxLineX){
        if(d>5000){confirm('ERROR EXCEED LIMIT WORDWRAP < WORD LENGTH, OR USE BREAK WORDS'); break; }; // protection freeze engine (win) if wrong wordWrap size
        if(data.type==='icon'){newLine = true; d--; continue; }; // reset to a newLine, but keep icons registered 

        // its a text need Split to a new line;
        var letterWidth = pixiBox.width / data.value.length; // calculate width of all letter
        var tmpW = 0; // Temps Width
        var skip = false;
        while ( (match = re.exec(data.value) ) !== null) {
            var mL = match[0].length; // match txt length 
            if(lineX+tmpW+(mL*letterWidth) > maxLineX){ // if this match exeed , txt befor index become this valur and add extra data after
                if(match.index===0){ // if match index 0 , (this data continue) reset new line 
                    console.log('=> how break and continue');newLine = true; d--; skip=true; break;
                }else{ // current txt become txt befor , and push new data after
                    data.value = match.input.slice(0, match.index); // text befor the match (if 0 its ok, just empty txt)
                    var after1 = this._newData('jmp', 0, "wordWrapBreak", false);
                    var after2 = this._newData('txt', match.input.slice(match.index), data.tag, data.style);
                    this._dataTxt.splice(d+1, 0, after1,after2); // reconfigu the loop length
                    pixiBox.text =  data.value; // redefine pixi
                    break;
                }

            };
            if(skip){continue;}
            tmpW+=lineX;
        };
    };
```

Comment: Do you mean that, in the case where you decide to end (break) the `while` loop, at that time you also want to immediately skip to the next iteration of the `for` loop (i.e. continue) without executing any code lower than the end of the `while` loop? If so, you'll need to set a flag in the while loop just before you break (using a boolean) and then check its status immediately after the end of the while loop. If it's true, then run a continue statement. Don't forget to reset it next the time `for` loop iterates.

Comment: yes you understand my problem.
This is where I block.
                if(match.index===0){ newLine = true; d--; break; continue; }

Comment: What do u mean you mean you want to halt the while loop and wait then continue it or you want to call continue?

Comment: yeah you can't write "continue" within the while loop, because a) you just broke out of the loop on the previous statement, so the continue will never run, and b) even if it did, it would try to continue the while loop, not the for loop. Dave's answer's second suggestion is basically what I just described.

Comment: yes, the 2 suggest are very good, I need to evaluate the performance of each.
The one who consumes less than MS
thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need are labels.

```
forloop:
    for(){
        whileloop: 
            while(){
                break whileloop;
            }
    }
```

This will exit the while loop but remain in the for loop. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Comment: This example is bad. You don't need tags here

Comment: very helpful and constructive comment, thanks @JonasW.

Comment: OMG, your are awsome thank, I did not know at all. thank you so much friend.

Comment: @JonasW. it is terser than the other proposed solutions, and very readable. What makes it bad in your opinion?

Comment: Again: the labels are useless here. May do `break forloop` to really make sth useful with labels

Comment: Again? I don't understand. @JonasW. I genuinely come here to learn and I'd expect someone with almost 20,000 reputation to be able to explain something better than `its useless`. If this is wrong then I want to know why

Comment: yes, the 2 suggest are very good, I need to evaluate the performance of each. The one who consumes less than MS thank you guys.
I just needed a track, I will study the 2 suggest.
thank a lot.

Comment: @Robbie Milejczak you have the true way. if i break , its jump my loop

Answer (score 2):

This is ugly IMO, but you can do:

```
outer: for(var d=0, newLine=true; d<dataTxt.length; d++){ // loop all dataTxt
       //...
           while ( (match = re.exec(data.value) ) !== null) {
           //...
               if(match.index===0){
                   continue outer;
               }
           }
       }
```

What I would probably do is:

```
for(var d=0, newLine=true; d<dataTxt.length; d++){ // loop all dataTxt
     //...
     var skip = false;
     while ( (match = re.exec(data.value) ) !== null) {
          if(match.index===0){
              skip = true;
              break;
          }
     }
     if (skip) {
         continue;
     }
     //...
}
```

Comment: thank a lot , i just learn somthing new

Comment: performance.now() give better result with your sugest , thanks